# How to show another div when clicking on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon ,

I know this question has been asked a lot of times here, but all the answers there are not working for the problem I have.

I have a div called  **.title3** . When the user clicks it I want another div called  **.Content3**  to be shown . But unfortunatelly it doesn't work the way I want to.

Here is a part of my html code where I found this problem :

```
<body style="background-color:#171717">

<div class="pseudo3">
     <div class="one3">
          <div class="Content3">
              <p class="close">X</p>
              <form action="order.php">
                <input type="text" value="First & Last Name">
                <input type="email" value="Your e-mail">
                <input type="text" value="Your phone number">
                <textarea>Write your feedback here</textarea>
                <button>Send</button>
              </form>
           </div>
           <div onmouseclick="showDiv()" class="title3">
                FEEDBACK
           </div>
      </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("title3");
      if ( x.click === true ){
        document.getElementsByClassName("Content3").style.display = "block";
      }
  }
    </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* The Form Style */

form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

form input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background-color: #171717;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-top: 0.15px solid #262323;
    border-left: 0.15px solid #262323;
    border-right: 0.15px solid #262323;
}

form textarea {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background-color: #171717;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-top: 0.15px solid #262323;
    border-left: 0.15px solid #262323;
    border-right: 0.15px solid #262323;
}

form button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background-color: #171717;
    border: 0.15px solid #262323;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus{
    background-color: #212020;
    border-top: 0.15px solid #1f1616;
    border-left: 0.15px solid #1f1616;
    border-right: 0.15px solid #1f1616;
}

/* Content3 style */

.Content3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display:none;
}

/* one3 style */

.one3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #141414;
}

/* pseudo3 style */

.pseudo3 {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #b95e1c;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ad7145;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(#b95e1c, #ad7145),
        linear-gradient(#b95e1c, #ad7145);
    background-size: 2px 100%;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* title3 style */

.one3 .title3 {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

/* close style */

.close{
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-size: 24px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-11px;
    top:-62px;
    z-index:3;
     border-top: 0.5px solid #1f1616;
    border-left: 0.5px solid #1f1616;
    border-right: 0.5px solid #1f1616;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #1f1616;
    padding:10px 17px;
    background-color:#212121;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.close:hover{
    background-color: #8b8b8b;
    color:#212121;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
function showDiv() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("title3");
      if ( x.click === true ){
        document.getElementsByClassName("Content3").style.display = "block";
      }
}
```

There are no error messages, but when I click my .title3 div it's not showing the div with class .Content3

Comment: Get elements by class name always return an array, try using 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("title3")[0]; i.e. the index value along with it, also in document.getElementsByClassName("Content3")[0].style.display , it might work for you @laurian, also if this is correct let me know i'll mark it as answer

Comment: It will maybe work , but I already solved my problem . Thank you @KaranTewari for help!

Comment: @KaranTewari it doesn't return an array. It returns a HTML collection which is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems in your code. I will try to cover most of them

1. You use `onmouseclick`. That is not a valid javascript event. Use `onclick`.
2. You are trying to assign to variable `x` the HTML element with class `title3`. Here are 2 problems:

   2.1. You do not need to assign the element you just clicked on to a variable inside the click function. You already have that element with `event.target`

   2.2. By using `getElementsByClassName` you get a HTML Collection not a single element. ( see the plural Elements word ) You can get it using `querySelector` or by adding an id to it and use `getElementById` ( see the singular Element ). But again, you do not need to retrive it like that. You can use the `event.target`. As you click on it.
3. `if ( x.click === true ){` . Why you need to check if the element is clicked, when the entire function is called only when that element is clicked ? Redundant check and not correct.
4. here again. See point 2.2
5. do not name your HTML attributes with capital letters. use `content3`
6. Do not import jquery, as you do not need it.

Check code below

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.querySelector(".Content3").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.Content3 {
  display:none
  }
```

```html
<div class="pseudo3">
  <div class="one3">
    <div class="Content3">
      <p class="close">X</p>
      <form action="order.php">
        <input type="text" value="First & Last Name">
        <input type="email" value="Your e-mail">
        <input type="text" value="Your phone number">
        <textarea>Write your feedback here</textarea>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div onclick="showDiv()" class="title3">
      FEEDBACK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Useful links:

- [onclick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)
- [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! 
You had a lot of patience writing all the things I did wrong :) Now I know what to do in the future :) This one is working! Can I request your help when I have more problems ?

Comment: @LaurianHurduza I pointed those things out to help you. That's the purpose of SO ( it should be ) .Glad i could help. Sure, just post questions here on SO and me or someone else will help you. ( or you can tag me in a comment so i get a notification about the question but i can't say 100% i will be able to help you right away ) . Cheers. And good luck !

Comment: Thank you! 
( p.s : I see you are romanian , I am romanian too :) It would be nice if we could speak on our own language here :)) )

Comment: @LaurianHurduza This is an english only website. So no other languages are allowed. Again, good luck and read the docs ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need jQuery to do that, you can also delete your onmouseover and use just this:

```
<script>
//add listener for click on your .title3
document.getElementsByClassName("title3")[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
   //prevent default action if any (dont need that in this case, but useful, if .title3 would be <a> tag)
   e.preventDefault(); 
   //set style
   document.getElementsByClassName("Content3")[0].style.display = "block";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me .. but this one it's not working .. I don't know that am I doing wrong .. I copied and paste the exact code you wrote , but no results.. Maybe if I make my div an anchor tag , will maybe solve the problem ?

Comment: check my answer. Do not use `getElementsByClassName` as it gets a HTML collection not an element.

Comment: That seems to work I think , but I already found my answer :) Thank you Pavel !

Answer (score -1):

Can you use `data` property for this topic.

```
<div class="titles">
    <button data-id="1">open 1</button>
    <button data-id="2">open 2</button>
    <button data-id="3">open 3</button>
</div>
<div class="contents">
    <p data-id="1">context</p>
    <p data-id="2">context</p>
    <p data-id="3">context</p>
</div>
```

When any button clicked, take `data-id` and do anything inside of contents div with `data-id`. If you cannot understand I can send any example for this.

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! Can you provide me an example for my code ?